# Web API JSON Property Length Limit?

Tags: c#, json, serialization, asp.net-web-api, size

I'm posting JSON to a C# Web API service from Objective-C. The POST method on the Web API controller automatically deserializes the post form data into the corresponding typed object in .Net.

The problem I am having is that one property, a simple string property, only receives a value if the string posted is of a small enough size. The information I'm posting up for the field is a Base64 encoded string representation of an image. If the image I use is small enough the property comes through perfectly. If the encoded image is a slightly larger size, say 80k, then it gets deserialized to an empty string.

Can someone please provide some information on how to control the maximum length / sizes involved in JSON deserialisation in Web API / MVC?

Comment: Ok, so after setting up remote azure debugging I've determined that the problem is not with the deserialisation of the json data. The problem is that I'm saving information to the database via an Entity Framework Type that has a property mapped to NVARCHAR(MAX). When saving, there's no error but the value is not stored. When I try to store the value via SQL statement in SQL Management Studio there is an error stating that the Base64 value would be truncated.

I can successfully store the info as a VarBinary column.

I thought the storage limit on a NVARCHAR(Max) was 2GB?

Answer (score 0):

i guess you are looking for this. Add this in web.config

```
<jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="maximumlengthhere" />
```

Comment: I came across this property and dismissed it as it seemed to be concerning the serialisation rather than the deserialisation. I'll give it a bash and let you know how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer below link : Hope it will help you

http://www.drdobbs.com/windows/parsing-big-records-with-jsonnet/240165316
http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/html/Performance.htm